# Is it possible to extract duplicate code in bean into single method?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, java-8, functional-programming

I have this cloud-gateway configuration and I would like to extract and clean up any duplicate code.

```
    @Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route("post_route", r -> r.path("/api/wallet/**")
                                             .and().method("POST")
                                             .and().readBody(BankRequestData.class, requestBody -> findWalletInstance(requestBody.externalReference()).equals("localhost:3000")).uri("http://localhost:3000"))
                  .route("post_route", r -> r.path("/api/wallet/**")
                                             .and().method("POST")
                                             .and().readBody(BankRequestData.class, requestBody -> findWalletInstance(requestBody.externalReference()).equals("localhost:3001")).uri("http://localhost:3001"))

                  .build();
}
```

Is this somehow possible? I am not sure if it can be done. Any suggestion or recommendation is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`route()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-gateway-core/2.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/route/builder/RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder.html#route-java.lang.String-java.util.function.Function-) take a `Function<PredicateSpec,Route.AsyncBuilder>`, so you need a method returning that.

Since the routes are the same, except for host and post, you'd need the pass that to the method.

```java
private Function<PredicateSpec,Route.AsyncBuilder> walletRoute(String server) {
    return r -> r.path("/api/wallet/**")
                 .and().method("POST")
                 .and().readBody(BankRequestData.class, requestBody ->
                         findWalletInstance(requestBody.externalReference()).equals(server))
                 .uri("http://" + server));
```

```java
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route("post_route", walletRoute("localhost:3000"))
                  .route("post_route", walletRoute("localhost:3001"))
                  .build();
}
```

Comment: Alternatives might be to define that function as a local function within `gatewayRoutes()`, or a local variable initialised to an anonymous function or lambda.  Those would avoid adding even a private member to the class, but would make `gatewayRoutes()` itself a bit more complex.  (All equally valid; more a matter of personal taste.)

Answer (score 1):

As variations on Andreas's answer, in Kotlin you could also define the function as a local function within `gatewayRoutes()`:

```
@Bean
fun RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(builder: RouteLocatorBuilder): routeLocator {

    fun walletRoute(server: String) = { r: PredicateSpec ->
        r.path("/api/wallet/**")
         .and().method("POST")
         .and().readBody(BankRequestData::class.java,
                         { findWalletInstance(it.externalReference()) == server } )
         .uri("http://$server")
    }

    return builder.routes()
                  .route("post_route", walletRoute("localhost:3000"))
                  .route("post_route", walletRoute("localhost:3001"))
                  .build()
}
```

Or as a local variable initialised to an anonymous function:

```
@Bean
fun RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(builder: RouteLocatorBuilder): routeLocator {

    val walletRoute = fun (server: String) = { r: PredicateSpec ->
        r.path("/api/wallet/**")
         .and().method("POST")
         .and().readBody(BankRequestData::class.java,
                         { findWalletInstance(it.externalReference()) == server } )
         .uri("http://$server")
    }

    return builder.routes()
                  .route("post_route", walletRoute("localhost:3000"))
                  .route("post_route", walletRoute("localhost:3001"))
                  .build()
}
```

Or to a lambda:

```
@Bean
fun RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(builder: RouteLocatorBuilder): routeLocator {

    val walletRoute = { server: String -> { r: PredicateSpec ->
            r.path("/api/wallet/**")
             .and().method("POST")
             .and().readBody(BankRequestData::class.java,
                             { findWalletInstance(it.externalReference()) == server } )
             .uri("http://$server")
        }
    }

    return builder.routes()
                  .route("post_route", walletRoute("localhost:3000"))
                  .route("post_route", walletRoute("localhost:3001"))
                  .build()
}
```

All these options would avoid adding a member to the containing class, which you may consider neater — though whether that justifies the more complex function body is probably a matter of personal taste!

(Note: all this is untested, as I don't have the relevant libraries, so it may have errors.  Please let me know of any corrections.  Hopefully it illustrates the options anyway.)